# İs there a way to reverse code for Css :root background color?

Tags: css

When I wanted to change the background color to `#E9ECEF`, I texted in `style.css` file

```css
root {
  --bg-body-color: #E9ECEF
}
```

it's changed every page's background color. Even old projects. I couldn't find a solution to reverse it. One code changed every page's bg-color even if new or in the same folder or old project with no bond with the present. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

What you are showing for code technically doesn't do anything by iteself.  All that is doing is creating a variable called --bg-body-color for you to use somewhere else on your page with the var keyword. because you defined that in root you can use that var as var(--bg-body-color) for a value with any css property in your document that is expecting a hex code.

What property did you use the var(--bg-body-color) on?

Aside from that, the only way it would affect other pages is if those other pages point to that same style.css. Its not uncommon for all pages in the same project to use that file, but other projects should not be pointing to that. If your other projects are in the same folder, and pointing to style.css then thats the problem. You should have each project you work on in its own directory(folder)

Comment: correct with one exception. Competent company developers will create one CSS file for all the projects (cooperate design, framework, style guide...) so they don't have to write the same CSS repeatedly.

Comment: It seems like var(--bg-body-color) was used in many projects in this case with the import of the same CSS file.  I would just revert it back to a classic color like #FFFFFF and track where var(--bg-body-color) was used in other projects to encapsule them.